# Open MPI 1.10 not seeing processes on Linux Mint 17

Tags: c, linux, mpi

I recently changed from Ubuntu 14 to Linux Mint 17. After re-installing Open MPI 1.10 (which went fine) I ran into a very strange problem:

I compiled my standard mpi_hello_world.c with mpicc and tried to run
it, (mpiexec -n 4 mpi_hello) but got the following output:

```
Hello world from processor DarkHeresy, rank 0 out of 1 processors
Hello world from processor DarkHeresy, rank 0 out of 1 processors
Hello world from processor DarkHeresy, rank 0 out of 1 processors
Hello world from processor DarkHeresy, rank 0 out of 1 processors
```

So the mpiexec is only running the process at rank 0!

I also tried to run a more complicated program, but it resulted a following error:

> Quitting. Number of MPI tasks (1) must be divisible by 4.

Earlier on Ubuntu, everything was running smoothly using the same parameters.
What could be wrong / how to solve this?

The hello world program was a standard one taken from [www.mpitutorial.com](http://www.mpitutorial.com):

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);


int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
int name_len;
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);


printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
     processor_name, world_rank, world_size);
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: You have more than one MPI implementations installed at the same time. Make sure that `mpicc`, `mpiexec`, and the MPI libraries picked by the dynamic linker all come from the same implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I simply removed the unnecessary mpi implementation and the problem disappeared.